# Making a sticky header work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code for a [sticky header](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/hair-and-beauty/hairdressers/vicky-newman-hair-and-make-up-598.html), but I can't get the scroll to work and it's not a smooth transition. The `#top-nav-wrapper` barely scrolls when the fixed header below is activated:

```
<script>
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value > 48 ) {
        $(".header").css("position", "fixed");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "90px");
    } else {
        $(".header").css("position", "relative");
        $("body").css("padding-top", "0");
    }
});
</script>
```

The 48 value is the height of the #top-nav-wrapper, plus it has a box-shadow.

The `.header` class with the search bar is what should remain.

The basic html:

```
<div class="headerWrapper">
    <div id="top-nav-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="header"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
  background: #EEE;
}

#top-nav-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px 0px #B8B8B8;
  z-index: 2001;
  background: #EEE;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 90px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background: #EEE;
  height: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #C4C4C4;
}
```

* I tried the following suggestion, but it's the same effect as before:

```
<script>
        $(window).scroll( function() {
            var value = $(this).scrollTop();
            var $body = $('body');
            var docked = $body.hasClass('docked');    

            if ( value > 48 ) {
                if( !docked ) {
                    $body.addClass('docked');
                }
            } else {
                if( docked ) {
                    $body.removeClass('docked');
                }
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Any ideas appreciated.

**Update** - I've changed the script to the following and placed it in the head - this resolves the top nav not scrolling dynamically and I added a placeholder div after the header and before the content with the same size height as the fixed header to keep the content where it should be (because the fixed header changes the natural flow), but there's still the lag/jump when the fixed header kicks in.

**Placeholder CSS:**

```
.headerPlaceholder {
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
display: none;
}
```

**Solution to top nav not scrolling all the way after 48px scroll height was set:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var div = $('.header');
        var div2 = $('.headerPlaceholder');
        var start = $(div).offset().top;

        $.event.add(window, "scroll", function () {
            var p = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
            $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');
            $(div2).css('display', ((p) > start) ? 'block' : 'none');
        });

    });
</script>
```

**To make it a smooth transition, there might need to be a slight delay and fadein/out effect, if anyone could help with that?**

Comment: Try using `$(window)` instead of `$(document)`. In your if condition, check for `>=` as well. Also, you'll want to bump up the z-index for the `.header` element (or, use a placeholder to prevent layout collapsing...minimizes need to use `padding-top`)

Comment: You should simply add a class to the body tag and use css to make the change for body and .header

Comment: Jack mentions the zindex is because the docked header is underneath the normal header. other than that it works for me on FF mac, what browser are you using?

Comment: Ah, I got you. BTW, @Huangism is right - adding a class to the body would make more sense - also addresses the box-shadow issue.

Comment: Website looks perfectly fine to me (Chrome, Win7x64)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    var $body = $('body');
    var docked = $body.hasClass('docked');    

    if ( value > 48 ) {
        if( !docked ) {
            $body.addClass('docked');
        }
    } else {
        if( docked ) {
            $body.removeClass('docked');
        }
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.docked {
    padding-top: 90px;
}
.docked .header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2005;
}
```

You can be more efficient if there is an overall container you can target instead of body.

Comment: Currently we are changing the .header class to fix/docked, if you want to target the top nav ID, then you can try changing that part. I am unclear of what box shadow issue you have. I have checked the site on different browsers on my mac and windows 7 VM. Everything looks fine and I did not have any issue scrolling or anything like that. Perhaps your computer is too old? Can you explain what you mean by not scrolling properly? I see everything as normal and working

Comment: Ok, I am on the news page. The top nav has a z-index of 2001. I don't know why this is needed and if not needed then you should remove it. When you remove the z-index, when the docked menu docks the header will no loner overlap the docked menu. So what I am seeing now is the "inside guide" section is docked. If this is correct, and you want the content to not 'jump', then it just a matter of adjusting the padding-top

Comment: There is no issue with the top nav not disappearing. We did not implement any css for the top nav to disappear nor do we need to. Bottom line is it doesn't need to disappear. I have updated the question to make the docked header z-index 2005 so there will be no overlap when it docks. It overlaps because the z-index on the top nav is higher than your docked header. Your top nav is position relative that's why it is overlapping your fixed positioned header. Make this update to your site and adjust the padding top. It looks like you need to add more padding since the content is jumping up.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not scrolling up and hides the problem. Is the top nav supposed to dock with the inside guide header?

Comment: Oh you mean visible due to the fact that your header is translucent? Why is this an issue? If you really want it to disappear then just add it to the css. Target the top nav with the docked class and just set it to display none. Or make the docked header opaque. This is simple css, let me know if you don't know how to do this

Comment: what do you mean scroll height issue? as in the content jumping? or a different issue? If it is the content jumping, that's just a matter of padding-top for docked class. Just adjust it until it fits perfectly. Example here http://www.lexus.ca/lexus/en/automobiles/ls I think we used margin top or something but the idea is the exact same

Comment: I see you went with still hiding the header. You should still do it by adding class as this is much more efficient. Since you are hidden the top nav, you must increase the padding-top higher to avoid the jump

Comment: you can simple make the top nav visibility hidden, this way it still takes up the same space but just not visible. This way you don't need the extra placeholder. If the jump is still there, that just means you need to increase or decrease your padding-top. It's not the content that's jumping, it's the fact that the fixed header is covering the top part of the page which why you must increase the padding-top even more. Increase it until it works. This is simple trail and error

Comment: Try doubling your padding top to 180px